# parsing multiple xml arrays in sql

Tags: sql-server, xml, arrays

Here's my setup: I am passing two arrays as XML into a SQL stored procedure.

These are:

```
<PhoneID Value=128/>
<PhoneID Value=129/>
<PhoneID Value=130/>
```

and

```
<AddressID Value=268/>
<AddressID Value=157/>
<AddressID Value=395/>
```

The `Address` and `Phone` tables look like this (pseudo-code follows):

```
Phone:

BIGINT PhoneID
BIGINT PhoneNumber
SMALLINT AreaCode
INT Extension

Address:

BIGINT AddressID
NVARCHAR StreetAddress
NVARCHAR CountryName
NVARCHAR City
BIGINT Zip
```

My dilemma is this:

I need to walk through the passed in arrays in lock-step to return

```
ContactInfo:

BIGINT PhoneNumber
NVARCHAR StreetAddress
BIGINT ZipCode
```

i.e. I need to return one ContactInfo built from Phone where PhoneID = 128 and Address where AddressID = 268, and another where PhoneID = 129 and AddressID = 268, etc.

My big question is: How do I walk two xml arrays in lock-step in sql?

This is in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: is there a reason you're doing this on the database and not in the application tier?

Comment: "i.e. I need to return one ContactInfo built from Phone where PhoneID = 128 and Address where AddressID = 268, and another where PhoneID = 129 and AddressID = 268, etc." -- no, not 'etc.'. What is the logic to this? Edit: or did you mean AddressID = 157 in the second one?

Comment: If you've got control over both sides (caller and stored proc), could you not pass a single XML document that groups the two parameters together (e.g. `<SearchTerm PhoneID="128" AddressID="268"/>`)

Comment: -Jon, you're right, I did mean AddressID = 157 in the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's possible to in T-SQL, like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[XmlParsingProcedure]
  @XmlArgs XML
AS
  SELECT * FROM SomeTable
  WHERE (s.XmlArgs IN (select x.XmlArgs.value('@Value','smallint') FROM @XmlArgs.nodes('//XmlArgs') as x(XmlArgs)))
```

However, intrinsic knowledge of the XML is required.
The above implies the XML schema:

```
<XmlArgs Value="some value"/>
<XmlArgs Value="some other value"/>
<XmlArgs Value="yet another value"/>
```

where both, 'XmlArgs' and 'Value' are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

The only viable approach I see is trying to do this:

- parse/shred your XML arrays into temporary tables for phones and addresses
- those temporary tables have an `ID INT IDENTITY` defined
- when inserting into a fresh temporary table with this INT IDENTITY, both sets of data will get consecutive numbering (1, 2, 3, 4......)
- you can then join the two temporary tables on their ID and should get your "lock-step" behavior:

So in code, this would look something like (mind you: your XML is invalid, too - the attribute values need to be in double quotes for this to work!):

```
DECLARE @phones XML = '<PhoneID Value="128"/><PhoneID Value="129"/><PhoneID Value="130"/>'

DECLARE @Addresses XML = '<AddressID Value="268"/><AddressID Value="157"/><AddressID Value="395"/>'

DECLARE @phoneTable TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, PhoneID INT)
DECLARE @AddressTable TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, AddressID INT)

INSERT INTO @phoneTable(PhoneID)
    SELECT
        PHID.value('(@Value)', 'int')
    FROM
        @phones.nodes('/PhoneID') AS PH(PHID)

INSERT INTO @AddressTable(AddressID)
    SELECT
        ADRID.value('(@Value)', 'int')
    FROM
        @addresses.nodes('/AddressID') AS AD(ADRID)

SELECT p.*, a.*
FROM @phoneTable p
INNER JOIN @addresstable a ON p.ID = a.ID
```

Does that work for you?? From here, you could then insert the data into your actual working tables and do any additional lookups or processing.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain that it's guaranteed that the IDENTITY values will match the "insertion" order, unless there's an ORDER BY clause in the `INSERT...SELECT` query. It may appear to work for small samples, and fail with larger queries

Comment: @Damien_the_unbeliever: yes, I agree - it's a bit "risky", but if there's nothing else to go on.... if you create new table variables, they're empty, and the ID will start at 1 for both - that's about as good as it gets without any better "handle" to tie the two parts together...